# Copy database outside APK

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to copy database from Asset folder , but ufortunetly i've got the errror: **System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/Northwind.sqlite" is denied.'** I added Runtime Permission. Could you tell me what am i doing wrong? Below is my source code:

```
 string dbName = "Northwind.sqlite";
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString(), dbName);
        // Check if your DB has already been extracted.
        if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(dbName)))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int len = 0;
                    while ((len = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        bw.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the stpes below. It works well on my side.

My database in Assets folder.

[image]

Set the Build Action as AndroidAssect.

[image]

You could use the following code to copy the file from Assects folder to Android Application folder

// Android application default folder.
            var dbFile = GetDefaultFolderPath();

```
        // Check if the file already exists.
        if (!File.Exists(dbFile))
        {
            using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(dbFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                // Assets is comming from the current context.
                await Assets.Open(databaseName).CopyToAsync(writeStream);
            }
        }
```

Download the source file from the link below.
https://github.com/damienaicheh/CopyAssetsProject